# The origin of the name UDP

Tags: udp

I was wondering,

UDP being broadly defined as a connection-less, unreliable protocol giving applications control over messages sequencing and flux control, is it correct to say that the *"User"* in User Datagram Protocol, indicates that the control of such things is passed onto the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "user" in this case is the application that UDP enables to send datagrams.

If you consider any network layering model (OSI, DoD, IP, ...), each layer has an underlying, lower layer that it uses and higher, more abstracted layer that it considers as "user".

UDP is a transport-layer protocol, so it uses the network layer and is used by the application layer.